# Is there a way to add middleware for a particular url route in django?

Tags: python, django, middleware

Say I have some URLs:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('', Home.as_view()),
    path('games/', include('games.urls', namespace='games')),
]
```

Is there a way that I can get a given middleware to run only when accessing urls under `games`? E.g. to check auth or to pre-fetch some data that will be useful to all views in the `games` app.

Answer (score 2):

You can check if current request belongs to `games` namespace by using [`ResolverMatch`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/urlresolvers/#django.urls.ResolverMatch):

```
def simple_middleware(get_response):
    # One-time configuration and initialization.

    def middleware(request):
        # Code to be executed for each request before
        # the view (and later middleware) are called.

        if 'games' in request.resolver_match.namespaces:
            # Some additional logic here
            pass

        response = get_response(request)

        # Code to be executed for each request/response after
        # the view is called.

        return response

    return middleware
```

Comment: Hi, I found this useful, but just wanted to note that I've found that request.resolver_match is not available until after the call to get_response

Comment: you can use resolver_match provided by django in process_view though.